# How do I make a DIV's background color spread the whole screen

Tags: html, css, background-color

I want to make the background color of a div bleed whole width and height of a screen at any size??

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="header-BG"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    }

#header-BG{ 

/* content */

}
```

Comment: To add to the above, there are many reasons why a div might not be filling the entire width and height of your screen. Without seeing more of your code, it's impossible to tell what might be causing it in your particular case. Try adding your code to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), and posting the link here. If you have an image showing what you want it to look like, post that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
#header-BG {
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-BG"></div>
```

Comment: thank you! exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @HenryBrown, for what it's worth this is an extension of my answer and is virtually doing the same thing. The div will take up the full width and height of the browser window just as the body would in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```css
html {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

or

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

Comment: This would make the background color for the entire site, I just want it for that particular div and to always fit the screen size

Comment: If the DIV is supposed to be the full height **and** width of the screen, why does that matter?